# Compute the following expression: $\prod^{99}_{i=10} \frac{i}{i+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

I understand the rules for summation now. But not product notation. This is what I have so far. Not sure if it is correct.[image]

Comment: Look at the product of fractions. You have some nice cancelation that can happen. I’m also not entirely sure where the sums come from; everything is being multiplied.

Comment: woops, meant to make those pi, not sigma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
$$\prod_{i=10}^{99}\frac{i}{i+1}=\frac{\prod_{i=10}^{99}i}{\prod_{i=10}^{99}(i+1)}$$
$$=\frac{\prod_{i=10}^{99}i}{\prod_{i=11}^{100}i}$$
$$=\frac{10\cdot\cancel{(\prod_{i=11}^{99}i)}}{\cancel{(\prod_{i=11}^{99}i)}\cdot 100}$$
$$=\frac{10}{100}$$
$$=\frac1{10}$$

Comment: Thank you!. I didnt know you could cancel like that

Comment: @CraigD : Note that I rewrote the numerator and denominator so that the common factors were explicit, then cancelled just those. Notice also that I rewrote the product in the denominator so that the generic term looked like the generic term in the numerator. If they don't look exactly alike (same generic term, same upper and lower limits), you can't cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $11$ cancels between the first and second terms.  Similarly, $12$ cancels between the second and third.  Like a telescoping addition series, most of the terms cancel.  You are left with ????

Comment: Ohh. I see.. 10/100?

Comment: Yes, that is correct